# Capping fermentor for carbonation

Tags: fermentation, carbonation, co2, capping

I'm just doing some reading, and it mentioned capping the fermenter to carbonate the beer by trapping the remaining co2. Has anyone given it a go? What were the results?

Comment: I would recommend to read this article (https://byo.com/stories/issue/item/1763-ferment-in-a-cornelius-keg-projects) on fermenting in a corny keg. It describes necessary procedures and equipment, and also explains pros and cons.

Comment: It's a very uncertain way to control carbonation and there's really nothing to be gained by it in terms of beer quality.

Answer (score 4):

Glass carboys are not rated for pressure, I would definitely not recommend trying it there.

If fermenting or finishing in a metal vessel (like a corny keg), you can use a [spunding valve](http://byo.com/stories/item/397-build-your-own-spunding-valve-to-carbonate-in-the-keg) to control the amount of pressure in the keg to force carbonation, similar to actively adding CO₂ to the keg to force carbonate after fermentation.

It's a practice born out of the Rhineheitsghebot about not using sugar to carbonate. Modern practices make it easier to carbonate with no ill effect on the beer, as Denny mentions.